# C# WebApi2 action not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this action:

```
    [ActionName("Find")]
    [HttpGet]
    public override IHttpActionResult Find(string number)
    {
        //Get customer by number...
    }
```

This is the route:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );
```

This is the trace:

```
System.Web.Http.Request;;;http://localhost:12345/api/Customers/Find?number=100  
System.Web.Http.Controllers;DefaultHttpControllerSelector;SelectController;Route='controller:Customer,action:Find'
System.Web.Http.Controllers;DefaultHttpControllerSelector;SelectController;Customer
System.Web.Http.Controllers;HttpControllerDescriptor;CreateController;
System.Web.Http.Controllers;HttpControllerDescriptor;CreateController;CustomerController
System.Web.Http.Controllers;CustomerController;ExecuteAsync;
System.Web.Http.Action;ApiControllerActionSelector;SelectAction;
System.Web.Http.Action;ApiControllerActionSelector;SelectAction;
System.Web.Http.Controllers;CustomerController;ExecuteAsync;
System.Net.Http.Formatting;DefaultContentNegotiator;Negotiate;Type='HttpError',
```

However, the action is not found. Is the route incorrect?

Comment: What is the actual error?  From the trace it looks more like you are getting a failure in the formatter.  It looks like routing is working just fine.

Comment: Just a 500 error. No exception thrown because the code doesn't reach the action. The second line 'System.Web.Http.Action;ApiControllerActionSelector;SelectAction;' doesn't include the action name so the action was not selected. If the action was selected the line would look like this: 'System.Web.Http.Action;ApiControllerActionSelector;SelectAction;SelectedAction Find()'

Answer (score 0):

Add the segment for "number" and define defaults for controller and number (set it as optional). Then it should work.

Example:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{number}",
            defaults: new { number = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Hope this helps. Have a nice day,

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My controller was inheriting from a base controller, and this base controller had to virtual methods called Find and they also had the same action name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can use data Annotation Route top of Action.

but this is not Recommend, because of conflict with encapsulation in OOP.